# using an image as a background in java

Tags: java, image, jframe

I'm working on java to implement an window that contain an image as a background.

here is the code i made

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class FenImage extends JFrame {

private JLabel question ;
private JButton valider ;
private JPanel pan ;


public FenImage()
{
    this.setTitle("Image");
    this.setBounds(200, 500,600,450);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel question = new JLabel(" \t \t L'image qu'on peux utiliser pour présenter ce mot est : ");
    //this.add(question);
    this.getContentPane().add(question,BorderLayout.NORTH);
   JPanel pan = new JPanel()
    {
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            ImageIcon m = new ImageIcon("1.jpg");
            Image monImage = m.getImage();
            g.drawImage(monImage, 0, 0,this);

        }
    };
   this.getContentPane().add(pan);
```

but when i run i get only the label i added .

what's the problem ? and how can i add it correctly

Comment: One way to [add a background image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23459402/300257) to a Swing GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the label to the panel instead of the frame

```
JLabel question = new JLabel(" \t \t L'image qu'on peux utiliser pour présenter ce mot est : ");
JPanel pan = new JPanel()
{
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            ImageIcon m = new ImageIcon("1.jpg");
            Image monImage = m.getImage();
            g.drawImage(monImage, 0, 0,this);

        }
};
pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
pane.add(question, BorderLayout.NORTH);
this.getContentPane().add(pan);
```

You should avoid loading resources within the paint methods as this can increase your memory usage a slow your painting

**Updated**

`ImageIcon(String)` assumes that the String value is reference to a file on the file system. Contents stored in your `src` directory will be will be built into your jar, which turns it into embedded resources.

In order to load these resources, you need to use `Class#getResource`, for example

```
ImageIcon m = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/1.jpg"));
```

This assumes the resource is in the default directory (top level directory) of your `src` directory

Comment: I add it , but the image still doesn't apear

Comment: Where is the image stored?

Comment: they are stored in  .src folder